# Java. Помогите понять задание с бинарным деревом

Tags: java, алгоритм, binary, дерево

Не совсем понимаю как построить само дерево.

В данной задаче рассматриваются бинарные деревья. На рисунке ниже показан пример бинарного дерева, состоящего из семи узлов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Двоичное дерево-это либо пустое дерево, либо узел (называемый корнем), содержащий одно целое значение и связанный с двумя другими двоичными деревьями. Нас интересуют пути (последовательности связанных смежных узлов), которые начинаются в корне и следуют за краями дерева (отмечены стрелками на рисунке выше). Например, последовательность узлов A, B, D является допустимым путем, а последовательность a, B, G-нет.

**[image: Проблема]**

Мы хотим найти максимальное количество различных значений, которые появляются на пути, начиная от корня дерева. Например, на пути, состоящем из узлов A, B, D, G, есть два различных значения (4 и 5). На пути A, C, E есть три различных значения (1, 4 и 6). 
Не существует пути, содержащего четыре или более различных значений.

Написать функцию: 
решение класса { public int solution (Tree T); }

это, учитывая двоичное дерево T, состоящее из N узлов, возвращает максимальное количество различных значений, которые появляются на пути, начинающемся с корня дерева T. например, учитывая дерево, показанное выше, функция должна возвращать 3.

**Технические подробности**

Двоичное дерево задается с помощью структуры данных указателя. Предположим, что приведены следующие объявления:

```java
public class Tree {
    public int x;
    public Tree l;
    public Tree r;
}
```

Пустое дерево представлено пустым указателем (обозначается null). Непустое дерево представлено указателем на объект, представляющий его корень. Атрибут x содержит целое число, содержащееся в корне, тогда как атрибуты l и r содержат левое и правое поддеревья двоичного дерева соответственно.

**Предубеждения**

Напишите эффективный алгоритм для следующих предположений: 
* N-целое число в диапазоне [1..50,000]; 
• высота дерева t (количество ребер на самом длинном пути от корня до листа) находится в диапазоне [0..3,500]; 
• каждое значение в дереве T является целым числом в диапазоне [1..Северный.]

---

@ИмяФамилия  Думал вот таки образом

```
public void  preOrder(Tree tree){
        if (tree == null){
            return;
        }

//тут делать что нибудь со значением листка
        preOrder(tree.l);
        preOrder(tree.r);
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём ваша проблема? Предоставьте свой вариант решения.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия проблема в том, что я не понимаю как построить дерево

Comment: Вам уже дан класс, описывающий узел, создайте экземпляр узла и приравняйте его `l` и `r` к каким-то новым узлам, сделайте то же самое с этими `l` и `r` и так далее.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия то есть мне не нужно писать конструктор ?
```java
Tree tree1 = new Tree();
Tree tree2 = new Tree();
Tree tree3 = new Tree();
tree1.x = 4;
tree1.r = tree2;
tree1.l = tree3;
tree2.x= 6;
tree3.x= 5;
```
Таким образом? ,

Comment: Да, затем ещё сколько вам нужно создаёте, и присоединяете уже к `tree2` и `tree3`. Можете конструктор со всеми полями написать.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия если создаю вот такой конструктор :
```java
public Tree(int x,Tree l,Tree r){ 
this.x = x; 
this.l = l; 
this.r = r; 
```
То при создании первого экземпляра в нем придется , прописывать все остальные .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удобства вы можете сделать два конструктора: для создания узла с числом и узла со связанными с ним узлами.

```java
public class Tree {
    public int x;
    public Tree l;
    public Tree r;

    public Tree(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Tree(int x, Tree l, Tree r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.l = l;
        this.r = r;
    }
}
```

Создание дерева будет выглядеть так:

```java
Tree tree = new Tree(4,
                new Tree(2, 
                        new Tree(5), null),
                new Tree(2,
                        new Tree(3,
                                new Tree(5),
                                new Tree(4)),
                        new Tree(2)));
```

Таким способом можно обойти всё дерево и получить максимальное количество различных номеров узлов в дереве:

```java
HashSet<Integer> gatheredValues = new HashSet<>();

public int solution(Tree tree) {
    if(tree == null) return gatheredValues.size();

    boolean notContains = !gatheredValues.contains(tree.x);
    if(notContains) gatheredValues.add(tree.x);

    if(gatheredValues.size() == 3) return 3;

    // int maxValue = Math.max(solution(tree.l),solution(tree.r)). заменено для экономии времени (узлов всё-таки может быть до 50 тысяч!)
    int lValue = solution(tree.l);
    int rValue = solution(tree.r);
    int maxValue = (lValue >= rValue) ? lValue : rValue;

    if(notContains) gatheredValues.remove(tree.x);

    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: а как мне его обходить если оно будет принимать такой вид?

Comment: А это уже другой вопрос. Подумайте сами, если ничего не надумаете, напишите. Тут ещё вопрос, в каком виде поступают данные. В виде массива строк, состоящих из буква типа A B C ... Y Z AA AB ... AZ BA ... BZ CA CB ...?

Comment: Есть вариант запоминать список текущих узлов, чтобы по порядку подбирать их буквенный номер в процессе подсчёта. Ещё вопрос, есть ли ограничение по времени и памяти? И как, всё-таки, вводятся данные?

Comment: В теории, такой алгоритм сможет посчитать результат за несколько секунд, но надо ещё проверить.

Comment: Дерево вроде как я построил. Насколько я понимаю буквы даны нам , для наглядности. И теперь думаю о том, как теперь обойти мое дерево, для того чтобы найти найти максимальное количество различных значений, которые появляются на пути, начиная от корня дерева. если путь возможен, только если на пути встречаются три  разных значения. Слишком много думал, ведь смысл задачи написание этой самой функции.

Comment: Если буквы даны для примера, задача очень сильно упрощается. Ваша первоначальная задумка по обходу дерева была правильной, вам нужно сохранить максимальное значение и увеличивать его, если найдено большее, когда значение будет равно трём, из метода можно сразу выходить.

Comment: Я перечитал задание, да, надо просто максимальное количество разных значений от корня найти.

Comment: @damcha я написал метод, если у вас ничего не получилось, могу показать.

Comment: Я буду рад , если вы поделитесь со мной ?

Comment: @damcha я вам помог?

Comment: да, большое спасибо , теперь я понял что не хватало в моей функции .